# Adjective clauses, phrases and appositives

Tags: adjective-phrases, appositives

I know we can reduce adjective clause to adjective phrase. We are able to make appositives when it is possible. Although I have learnt some materials about it, I haven't seen examples with "where" and "when" yet. I mean, is it possible to find appositives or adjective phrases with "where" or "when"? As far as I suppose, adjective clauses with them are some kind of "special" clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**where**, **when** and **why** can be used as [relative adverbs](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/relative-adverbs/) that are used to replace a preposition + **which** when making a relative clause, for example

> Last week I visited the town **in which** I grew up
>   Last week I visited the town **where** I grew up